# Prevent Custom View from reacting to horizontal scroll

Tags: android, gesturedetector

I have a custom scrollable view - this view extends View and not ScrollView/ListView

Instead it has a Simple OnGestureListener
It does well on the vertical scroll - Now I've embedded it inside a ViewPager
And in order to scroll the viewpager, i need to make sure to put my finger outside of the given view to be able to scroll between pages

What can I do to prevent my view from accepting the scroll if it is horizontal ?

```
public WheelScroller(Context context, ScrollingListener listener) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            // Do scrolling in onTouchEvent() since onScroll() are not call immediately
            //  when user touch and move the wheel
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            lastScrollPosition = 0;
            scrollerFling(lastScrollPosition, (int) velocityX, (int) velocityY);
            setNextMessage(MESSAGE_SCROLL);
            return true;
        }



    });
    gestureDetector.setIsLongpressEnabled(false);

    scroller = new Scroller(context);

    this.listener = listener;
    this.context = context;
}

/**
 * Set the the specified scrolling interpolator
 * @param interpolator the interpolator
 */
public void setInterpolator(Interpolator interpolator) {
    scroller.forceFinished(true);
    scroller = new Scroller(context, interpolator);
}

/**
 * Scroll the wheel
 * @param distance the scrolling distance
 * @param time the scrolling duration
 */
public void scroll(int distance, int time) {
    scroller.forceFinished(true);
    lastScrollPosition = 0;
    scrollerStartScroll(distance, time != 0 ? time : SCROLLING_DURATION);
    setNextMessage(MESSAGE_SCROLL);
    startScrolling();
}

/**
 * Stops scrolling
 */
public void stopScrolling() {
    scroller.forceFinished(true);
}

/**
 * Handles Touch event 
 * @param event the motion event
 * @return
 */
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            lastTouchedPosition = getMotionEventPosition(event);
            scroller.forceFinished(true);
            clearMessages();
            listener.onTouch();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (scroller.isFinished())
                listener.onTouchUp();
            break;


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // perform scrolling
            int distance = (int)(getMotionEventPosition(event) - lastTouchedPosition);
            if (distance != 0) {
                startScrolling();
                listener.onScroll(distance);
                lastTouchedPosition = getMotionEventPosition(event);
            }
            break;
    }

    if (!gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event) && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        justify();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write a `custom ViewPager` for handeling the events like this:

```
public class SelectiveViewPager extends ViewPager {
    private boolean paging = true;

    public SelectiveViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SelectiveViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        if (paging) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setPaging(boolean p) {
        paging = p;
    }

}
```

on your rating view, use this pager instance and `setPagging(true or false);`  with respect to touch inside or out side.  here `onInterceptTouchEvent()` is handeling the touch event together.

check this link for more reference. [onInterceptTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)

Comment: I dont want to stop the viewpager from paging, i want to allow the view pager to receive the horizontal scroll event, which my current vertical scroll view is preventing

Comment: try this:  in  onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) return false;

Answer (score 0):

On the fling method check the y values from both motion events. Like so:

```
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        //You can set the threshhold to an amount you think is enough to detect a horizontal scroll. 
        //This means the difference between the fingers position on the y axis didn't change too much, so it was a horizontal scroll not a vertical one.
        boolean horizontalScroll = Math.abs(e1.getY()-e2.getY())<HORIZONTAL_SCROLL_THRESHHOLD;
        if(!horizontalScroll) {
        lastScrollPosition = 0;
        scrollerFling(lastScrollPosition, (int) velocityX, (int) velocityY);
        setNextMessage(MESSAGE_SCROLL);
        }

        return !horizontalScroll; 
        //If it was horizontal scroll it will return false so the event get's passed behind.
    }
```